# Could rocket fuel be mass produced in Ceres?

Tags: fuel, ceres

According to

[NASA rocket fuel Mars](https://www.wired.co.uk/article/nasa-rocket-fuel-mars)

> Liquid methane could be used as the fuel, produced from carbon dioxide
>   and water found on Mars.

If NASA is "working on it", there has to be many technical aspects for doing this viable in Mars, and Ceres doesnt have carbon dioxide, but supposedly it has water and carbonate minerals such as Siderite, which apparently under certain conditions can be transformed into Methane. [Methane production from hydrothermal transformation of siderite to magnetite](https://ui.adsabs.harvard.edu/abs/2012AGUFM.P13A1910M/abstract)

Now the massive extraction of those minerals and the establishment of a plant for mass producing them it's a different story and it has to have several obstacles

Could rocket fuel be mass produced in Ceres?

Comment: To burn methane as fuel oxygen is needed too.

Comment: With water alone, also rocket fuel could be produced, but the energy from the Sun there is at least 6 times less intense than on Earth.

Comment: It would not be difficult to liberate the CO2 from the carbonate minerals and use the standard Sabatier reaction. Applying heat would be the most straightforward approach, and would involve temperatures similar to those needed for the Sabatier reaction itself.